# Custom use of brackets like NamedTuple

Tags: julia

Brackets in Julia are used for Parametric Types as far as I encountered by now.
There is however one example of curly brackets being used in a different way:

```
NamedTuple{(:a, :b)}((1, 2))
```

This constructs the NamedTuple `(a=1, b=2)`, but you pass the field names in brackets.
The source code for the NamedTuple is a bit obscure in my opinion.

```
NamedTuple() = NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}(())

NamedTuple{names}(args::Tuple) where {names} = NamedTuple{names,typeof(args)}(args)

eval(Core, :(NamedTuple{names,T}(args::T) where {names, T <: Tuple} =
             $(Expr(:splatnew, :(NamedTuple{names,T}), :args))))
```

- Does the creation of a NamedTuple rely on macros/metaprogramming?
- What does `:splatnew` do?
- How would you approach making your own custom use of brackets?

Comment: "Does the creation of a NamedTuple rely on macros/metaprogramming?" No, but there is a type constructor macro `@NamedTuple` saving a few key strokes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is however one example of curly brackets being used in a different way:

They are used in the same way. Field names are parameters of a `NamedTuple`. To see this check:

```
julia> typeof((a=1, b=2))
NamedTuple{(:a, :b), Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
```

The only issue is that you are omitting passing the second parameter, which is `Tuple{Int64, Int64}` in this case but Julia allows omitting passing all parameters in this case. The reason why you can omit them is handled in this code you quoted:

```
NamedTuple{names}(args::Tuple) where {names} = NamedTuple{names,typeof(args)}(args)
```

which expands the parameters to include the tuple as a second parameter.

> Does the creation of a NamedTuple rely on macros/metaprogramming?

Yes, the code:

```
eval(Core, :(NamedTuple{names,T}(args::T) where {names, T <: Tuple} =
             $(Expr(:splatnew, :(NamedTuple{names,T}), :args))))
```

evaluates the expression in `Core` module. This is metaprogamming (but not macro).

> What does `:splatnew` do?

As you can read in [Julia Manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/ast/) it is:

> Similar to `new`, except field values are passed as a single tuple. Works similarly to `splat(new)` if new were a first-class function, hence the name.

So essentially it is `new` but accepting one positional argument that is a tuple that gets splatted.

> How would you approach making your own custom use of brackets?

This is not a custom use of brackets. The semantics follows standard parametric type rules.